# How to use fake_braintree for testing a rails app given that non-test code hits the actual Braintree API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I'm having some trouble testing a Braintree rails app using fake_braintree. I'm not using rspec, and maybe that is part of the problem.

In my tests, I interact with FakeBraintree---adding customers there, etc... But in the non-test code, I pull data from the Braintree API itself. Thus, when my tests hits the non-tests code, the code connects to the Braintree Sandbox, but (of course) the customer created via FakeBraintree is not there. It doesn't seem to me that I want to do anything atypical, and I'm unclear how I should be using fake_braintree, and having trouble finding clear documentation. Maybe the problem is trying to do this without using rspec?

thanks!

Comment: Hey bissej. Are you sure the methods that are hitting braintree are ones supported by fake_braintree? You also might have more luck asking for help on the github project instead of here.

Comment: agj: thanks for responding. So, to clarify, if the methods that hit Braintree are supported by fake_braintree, then they should automatically hit fake_braintree instead when called from the test environment?

Comment: I've not used the library myself, but I believe that's how it's supposed to work, yes.

Comment: Curious to know if you got this figured out?

Comment: agf: I've been sidetracked with other things, and haven't looked into it much more. So I haven't yet figured it out, but hopefully I will with some more effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I came back to this after some time, and the solution was surprising (or to me at least). If the test environment has access to the Braintree sandbox, then it connects there rather than fake_braintree. So in order to get the tests with fake_braintree to work, I had to reconfigure my configurations so that the braintree configuration variables were not set for the test environment.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I would have never figured that out myself.